Expo go client not working with Ubuntu, blank loading screen no error log
I'm currently setting up universal app project along with next.js and react native. Using expo SDK 49 and required client version in the mobile.
But when run the expo start, which shows only blank screen with loader no error logs in ubuntu 22.04 on same wifi connection.
To confirm the platform issue, I tried with same project in windows 11, which works fine.
